# What's happening to new lines in my form textarea?

Tags: php, forms

I have a really simple form consisting of a textarea. Within the textarea is MarkDown syntax which I want to save to a database. Obviously it's really important to preserve any carriage returns/new lines.

When the form is submitted though, the newlines don't seem to be sent to the server unless I use the `nl2br()` PHP function.

On the server, I grab the contents of the message textarea like this:

```
$content = $_POST['message'];
```

If I echo this with:

```
echo $content;
```

The text is on one long line.

If I echo with:

```
echo nl2br($content);
```

It shows the content as expected. Why is this? I'm assuming that if I just save the value of $content to my database that the new line characters will be preserved?

Comment: Browsers don't honor line feeds/carriage returns. They're treated as spaces and rendered as such. That's why nl2br works. it replaces the `\n` and `\r` characters with the html `<br>` tags. If you'd done a "view source" on your page, you'd have seen the raw source does contain the line breaks. Never trust what your browser shows, because its job is to lie to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser submits newlines as LF characters (=`\n`).

If you output these, the browser won't display them because it ignores newlines in the normal HTML rendering mode. Only if you convert them to `<br>` tags, the browser will recognize them.

Try setting the content type to `text/plain` and you will see that your browser also renders line feeds:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $content;
```

Save your data unformatted to your database, i.e. do **not** convert them to `<br>` tags. Do this conversion when you're outputting the data.

Comment: Alternatively you could output the text inside of `pre` tags or an element styled with `white-space:pre-line;`